# How to share context sub files - nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js

This is my pages:

```
/pages
   /gift
      /[slug]
         index.tsx
   /personalize
      index.tsx
```

I have a `GiftProvider` inside `/gift/[slug]/index.tsx`:

```
  return (
    
      <GiftProvider gift={gift}>
         <ProductPage />
```

user can see `/personalize/index.tsx` inside `ProductPage` component with a function:

```
  const goToPersonalize = () => {
    router.push(`/gift/${gift.id}/personalize`)
  }

          ....
```

now I have a `gift` state inside `/gift/[slug]/index.tsx`. (init this with SSG)
How I can access to this state inside `personalize`?

Comment: Use redux and in the personalise/index component just get the gift you need to personalise using the `gift.id`.

Comment: you can use `GiftProvider` in `_app.js`, and inside `gift/[slug]/index.tsx`  just update the state with `gift`

Answer (score 1):

I would separate `GiftProvider` from the page, and expose a custom hook for updating/reading the state.

Ex. `./components/giftProvider`

```
const GiftContext= React.createContext(null)

export function GiftProvider ({ children }) {
    const [gift,setGift] = useState(null)
    
    return (
        <GiftContext.Provider  value={{gift,setGift}} >
            {children}
        </GiftContext.Provider>
    )
}

export function useGift() {
    const value = useContext(AuthContext)
    return value
}
```

Now wrap every page inside `GiftProvider` :

`_app.js`

```
import { GiftProvider } from './components/giftProvider'
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <GiftProvider>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </GiftProvider>
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

Then  you can set the gift using your custom hook whereever you need to :

```
import {useGift} from '../../components/giftProvider '

    ....
    
        const {gift,setGift} = useGift()
        let mygift = "something" // the gift object
        setGift(mygift )
        
    ....
```

In the same way you can get current gift (ex. inside `/personalize/index.tsx`):

```
import {useGift} from '../../components/giftProvider '

....

    const {gift} = useGift()
    
....
```

If you want to persist your state (ex. store gift in local storage), you can change `setGift` function to store data, and add `useEffect` inside `giftProvider` to determine if there is already a gift stored.
Something like this :

```
 export function GiftProvider ({ children }) {
        const [gift,setGift] = useState(null)
        useEffect(()=>{
            let storedGift = localStorage.getItem('gift') ? localStorage.getItem('gift') : {} ;
            setGift(JSON.parse(storedGift)
        },[])
        
        const setNewGift = (giftObject) => {
            localStorage.setItem('gift', JSON.stringify(giftObject));
            setGift(giftObject)
        }
        
        return (
            <GiftContext.Provider  value={{gift,setGift,setNewGift}} >
                {children}
            </GiftContext.Provider>
        )
    }
```